# Error in AWS DMS replication from SQL Server to s3

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-dms

I have made all the connections to a SQL Server database to s3 by DMS, but during replication running i am getting error for few tables having names like `'Chronology event$'` (the quotes are also in table name) and cloudwatch throws this error:

> 2023-11-22T15:26:50 [SOURCE_UNLOAD   ]E:  sqlserver_fill_table_partitioners_names(...)
> Failed to create statement:
> select pf.name AS PartitionFunctionName, c.name AS PartitionKey FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS pstats INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON pstats.partition_id = p.partition_id INNER JOIN sys.destination_data_spaces AS dds ON pstats.partition_number = dds.destination_id INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS ds ON dds.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id INNER JOIN sys.partition_schemes AS ps ON dds.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id INNER JOIN sys.partition_functions AS pf ON ps.function_id = pf.function_id INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON pstats.object_id = i.object_id AND pstats.index_id = i.index_id AND dds.partition_scheme_id = i.data_space_id AND i.type <= 1 INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic ON i.index_id = ic.index_id AND i.object_id = ic.object_id AND ic.partition_ordinal > 0 INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON pstats.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id WHERE pstats.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].['Chronology event$']', N'table') group by pf.name, c.name [1022505]  (sqlserver_endpoint_metadata.c:1541)

I think this is coming due to the single quote also in table name or maybe due to $ sign in the table name. Is there any way to avoid this error in AWS DMS ?